# How does Mathematica calculate LaguerreL

Tags: polynomials, special-functions, implementation-details

About the function `LaguerreL[n,a,x]`, the helping documents in *Mathematica* only say that this function satisfies equation $xy^{\prime\prime}+(a+1-x)y^\prime+ny=0$. Is there an integral expression for this function? And how does *Mathematica* calculate the value of `LaguerreL[n,a,x]` when `n` is not a integer or when `n < 0` ?

Comment: From my recollection, the orthogonal polynomials in *Mathematica* are evaluated using the three-term recurrence for integer order, and the hypergeometric form (as shown in Bob's answer) for arbitrary orders.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From [Wolfram MathWorld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/AssociatedLaguerrePolynomial.html),

[image]

EDIT : added definition using `Hypergeometric1F1Regularized` based on comment by @ilian and his [reference](http://functions.wolfram.com/HypergeometricFunctions/LaguerreL3General/02/)

```
LaguerreL[n, a, x] ==
  Pochhammer[a + 1, n]/n! Hypergeometric1F1[-n, a + 1, x] ==
  Gamma[a + n + 1]/Gamma[n + 1] Hypergeometric1F1Regularized[-n, a + 1, 
    x] // FullSimplify
```

> True

One of these definitions may be how it is implemented.

EDIT 2: To address a question in the comments about `LaguerreL[-1, -1, x]`

```
Clear[a, n]

With[{n = -1, a = -1}, LaguerreL[n, a, x] // FunctionExpand]
```

> (-E^x)*x

The `Hypergeometric1F1Regularized` representation gives the same expression for (a == -1) and in the limit as (n -> -1)

```
 With[{a = -1}, 
 Limit[Gamma[a + n + 1]/Gamma[n + 1] Hypergeometric1F1Regularized[-n, a + 1, 
     x] // FunctionExpand, n -> -1]]
```

> (-E^x)*x

Visually comparing plots of `LaguerreL[-1, -1, x]` with `-x E^x`

```
Plot[{LaguerreL[-1, -1, x], -x E^x}, {x, -2, 1.25}, PlotStyle -> {
   Directive[Red, AbsoluteDashing[{10, 7}]],
   Directive[Blue, AbsoluteDashing[{5, 10}]]},
 PlotLegends -> "Expressions"]
```

[image]

However, taking the limit along different paths gives different results. Presumably, the internal Mathematica imlementation for `LaguerreL[n, a, x]` effectively uses the limit above.

Comment: Correct, you can also see it by evaluating ``Needs["GeneralUtilities`"]; PrintDefinitions[LaguerreL]`` +1

Comment: @Pickett I am surprised `PrintDefinitions` would give anything since the implementation is in `C` and not top level. +1 from me too, I believe the general case is computed in terms of `Gamma`/`Pochhammer` and `Hypergeometric1F1Regularized` as in this [definition](http://functions.wolfram.com/HypergeometricFunctions/LaguerreL3General/02/)

Comment: @Pickett Oh, I see now, it also has a few top level definitions attached related to `Series`.

Comment: To simplify even further, you can replace the `Pochhammer` symbol by `Binomial[a + n, n]`.

Comment: Thanks a lot! But I still have a question: run the following codes in Mathematica n = -1
a = -1
LaguerreL[n, a, x] // FunctionExpand
Gamma[a + n + 1]/Gamma[n + 1] Hypergeometric1F1Regularized[-n, a + 1, 
   x] // FunctionExpand          You will find that the LaguerreL turns out to be -x*Exp[x], but the latter function is not convergent. In this condition, how does Mathematica calculate LaguerreL?

Comment: @MenzelWang - Re: `LaguerreL[-1, -1, x]` see EDIT 2 in the answer.

Answer (score 4):

Here is an example that shows that a generic `LaguerreL` function is **not** automatically computed using the confluent hypergeometric function as suggested by MathWorld.

First I'll define the rule that would amount to just such a replacement. Then I'll show that this replacement allows a particular integral of the `LaguerreL` function to be computed without any assumptions. Finally, I *omit* the replacement rule and leave `LaguerreL` to be evaluated by *Mathematica* internally.

The result is that the integral is returned unevaluated if you don't make the replacement manually. This means that the generic `LaguerreL` was not internally replaced by the hypergeometric function:

```
laguerreReplacement = 
  LaguerreL[n_, k_, x_] :> 
   Binomial[k + n, n] Hypergeometric1F1[-n, 1 + k, x];

FullSimplify[(LaguerreL[n, k, x] /. laguerreReplacement) == 
  LaguerreL[n, k, x]]

(* ==> True *)

Clear[n];
Integrate[
 E^(-r - r/(n + 2)) LaguerreL[n, 3, (2 r)/(n + 2)] r^3 /. 
  laguerreReplacement, {r, 0, Infinity}]
```

> $(-n-1)^n (n+1) \left(-\frac{1}{n+2}\right)^n (n+3)^2
>    \left(\frac{n+3}{n+2}\right)^{-n-5}$

```
Integrate[
 E^(-r - r/(n + 2)) LaguerreL[n, 3, (2 r)/(n + 2)] r^3, {r, 0, Infinity}]
```

> $\int_0^{\infty } e^{-r-\frac{r}{n+2}}
>    L_n^3\left(\frac{2 r}{n+2}\right) r^3 \, dr$

There are many similar integrals where this happens. What this means is that the answer to the question of how the Laguerre function is evaluated internally seems to depend on the context. Here, it's not even a matter of assuming that the index is integer or positive. The above test involved only a generic `n`. Still the hypergeometric function was apparently not automatically introduced, even though it would have allowed the integral to be solved.

**Edit: testing alternative representation**

The replacement above is the one suggested by [MathWorld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/AssociatedLaguerrePolynomial.html) as copied in Bob Hanlon's answer. The other representation mentioned by [the function reference](http://functions.wolfram.com/HypergeometricFunctions/LaguerreL3General/02/) is tested below for the same integral:

```
laguerreReplacement = 
  LaguerreL[n_, k_, x_] :> 
   Gamma[k + n + 1]/Gamma[n + 1] Hypergeometric1F1Regularized[-n, 
     k + 1, x];

FullSimplify[(LaguerreL[n, k, x] /. laguerreReplacement) == 
  LaguerreL[n, k, x]]

(* ==> True *)

Integrate[
 E^(-r - r/(n + 2)) LaguerreL[n, 3, (2 r)/(n + 2)] r^3 /. 
  laguerreReplacement, {r, 0, Infinity}]
```

> $\text{ConditionalExpression}\left[(-1-n)^n (1+n)
>    \left(-\frac{1}{2+n}\right)^n (2+n) (3+n)
>    \left(1+\frac{1}{2+n}\right)^{-4-n},\Re\left(\frac{1
>    }{2+n}\right)>-1\right]$

Again, with the alternative manual replacement, *Mathematica* is able to do the integral. This means that this is also **not** the representation chosen automatically by *Mathematica* inside the integral (because whatever it is, it doesn't allow computation of the integral, as shown above).

Clearly, I don't have a definitive answer as to what *Mathematica* does internally. Instead, I am just eliminating some possibilities that could be generically valid.

Comment: Well, the Laguerre function can be represented through either the Kummer or Tricomi confluent hypergeometric function; I suppose it will use the Tricomi representation in the case that one would need to take a limit with the Kummer representation.

Comment: @J.M. Maybe - at least it's clear (I think) that the statement about the implementation on [MathWorld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/AssociatedLaguerrePolynomial.html) doesn't quite tell the whole story.